# Forecasting Multiple Time Series Prediction using LSTM

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, embedding

I am trying to forecast the demand of an item per week using LSTM network altogether.For this purpose, I am using the  Rossmann Sales data from Kaggle. It looks like this:

```
date     date_block_num shop_id item_id item_price  item_cnt_day
02.01.2013  0   59  22154   999 1
03.01.2013  0   25  2552    899 1
05.01.2013  0   25  2552    899 -1
06.01.2013  0   25  2554    1709.05 1
```

1. I am not able to figure out how to input this data into the LSTM network. In most of the examples that I came across, input is feed by selecting only one item_id and store_id. I want to feed all the items altogether.If I use [timeseriesgenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator),then timesteps of one item_id may mix up with the other.Hence, model won't be able to learn perfectly.
2. I am thinking to use an embedding layer for categorical variables: item_id and shop_id. But how will I reshape the output of Embedding layer according to the input of LSTM.

Please help me in solving this issue.
Thanks